# Como verificar se um item já foi introduzido numa lista em c#

Tags: c#

1. Existe a lista **turmas**
2. Dentro dessa lista eu coloco objectos do tipo **turma**
3. Cada objecto possui **(string)nomeTurma.Text** & um valor numérico **(int)numericUpDown1.Value**
4. Utilizo o método **addTurma** para colocar os objectos na lista **turmas**

   ```
       public static List<turma> turmas = new List<turma>();

       public static void addTurma(turma x)
       {

           turmas.Add(x);

       }
    turma x = new turma(nomeTurma.Text,(int)numericUpDown1.Value);
    //Se nomeTurma.Text não exite na lista turmas
     {
     turma.addTurma(x);
     }
   ```

Quero apenas adicionar **objectos do tipo turma** que não tenham o mesmo nome ou seja, verificar se  **(string)nomeTurma.Text** já existe na lista **turmas**

Comment: Faz um for na lista e vê se existe comparando os dois, ve se existe se algum igual e controla com uma bool

Comment: @BrunoH. Não existe nenhuma outra forma, não tem tipo um metodo que já faça isso proprio das listas ?

Comment: Tem, use o .Any().

Comment: @Francisco como uso o .Any ?

Comment: @AmadeuAntunes Linq para mim é igual regex, sei como funciona, mas não faço nem ideia de como usa kkkkkk De qualquer forma, você pode ver na documentação e talvez achar a expressão que precisa para fazer essa verificação: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb534972(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Vai ser algo assim: `bool existeNome = turmas.Any(p => p.Nome == nomeTurma.Text);`

Comment: Você pode também fazer um `If` caso não exista você adiciona, tipo:`if(!turmas.Any(p => p.Nome == nomeTurma.Text){...})`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45400646/how-to-check-if-item-already-is-in-list-c-sharp/45400737#45400737  ajudaram me assim

Comment: Já esta aberta a pergunta ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(turmas.Any(t => t.Text == text))  
{

}
```